# Change jQueryUI Accordion Header Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'd like to change the header's text using a jQueryUI accordion. I have it working, but the code is really messy... I do it the following way. I do it this way because I want to keep the span that is used to display the maximize/minimize icon. Here I change the first indexed header text.

```
var html = $('#selector-header-0').html().split('>');
var span = '';
for (var i = 0; i < html.length - 1; ++i)
    span += html[i] + '>';
$('#selector-header-0').empty();
$('#selector-header-0').append(span + 'New Header');
```

What I'd like to do is something like this.

```
$(#selector 0).header = 'New Header';
```

I know that the accordion has a header option but it seems to be used to change the header size. http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution I can think of is to proactively add a span around your H3 text so you can still easily target it directly once accordion adds its image icons alongside it.It'd be nice if the UI widget did this for you.

Key HTML:

```
<h3><span class="accordion-header">Section 1</span></h3>
```

Key javascript:

```
$("#accordion").find($("#accordion").accordion( "option", "header" ))
.eq(0) //which do you wish to target?
.find($("span.accordion-header")).text("Section " + Math.random());
```

Semi-working JSFiddle (doesn't apply the style): http://jsfiddle.net/8KANL/

Full working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>accordion demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="renamefirst" type="button" value="Rename First Accordion Header" min=0></input>
<input id="renamesecond" type="button" value="Rename Second Accordion Header" min=1></input>
<input id="renamelast" type="button" value="Rename Last Accordion Header" min=2></input>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3><span class="accordion-header">Section 1</span></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget.
    Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in,
    condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros.
    Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio.</p>
  </div>
  <h3><span class="accordion-header">Section 2</span></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus.
    Vivamus hendrerit, dolor aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis velit,
    faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.</p>
  </div>
  <h3><span class="accordion-header">Section 3</span></h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus.
    Quisque lobortis.Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$( "#accordion" ).accordion();

$("input").click( function() {
   $( "#accordion" ).find($( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "header" )).eq(this.min).find($("span.accordion-header")).text("Section " + Math.random());
});

</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying... I had attempted something similar to this but it resulted in the span being removed (which stores the icon).

Comment: Alright, provided a shiny new answer which relies on wrapping your text in a span.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I agree that this should be encapsulated into the UI widget.